# Meaning of それと in this context

Tags: grammar

I have a question about the meaning of それと in the following sentence. Does it has the meaning "and, also" here, so both 「何かのタンクや配管といった」 and 「めぼしい」 modifies 危険物?

Some sort of translation:
Driving through the narrow passage I was throwing thermite grenades, every time I seen some/with something(?) tanks or pipes and other dangerous looking objects.

俺は狭い通路を次々と駆け抜けながら、何かのタンクや配管といった、**それとめぼしい**危険物を見つけるたびに、携え持ったテルミット手榴弾【しゅりゅうだん】を投下した。

Comment: Does it really say 「めぼしい」?

Comment: @l'électeur 何かおかしいですか？「それ（＝危険物）ではないかと思われる、目立ってそう見える」みたいな感じではないかと思ったんですが・・

Comment: @l'électeur ああ、「それと[思]{おぼ}しき」ではないか、ということですね？

Comment: @choco 「おぼしい」の間違いでは、という意味です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

めぼしい is a additive form of [目星]{めぼし}. (Note that you usually write めぼしい in Hiragana, where you usually write 目星 in Kanji.) 目星 means "what you think something you are looking for", or "something it looks like what you are looking for". For example, [殺人犯]{さつじんはん}の目星 means "a person that you think is a killer".

So, それとめぼしい menas "something looks like it".

危険物 menas a dangerous thing. If you put "それとめぼしい" before it, it means only dangerous things that looks like what you are looking for.

何かのタンクや配管 is just talking about the examples of "それとめぼしい危険物".

Comment: Thank you, I'm a bit confused though, this と before それ is a quotative と? In this case, similar to それ**という**めぼしい危険物?

Comment: @DarkAkira I'm not sure it is a quotative, but それというめぼしい危険物 sounds all right to me.